Domain of pmf for Poisson random variable
What is the domain of the probability mass function for a random variable with a Poisson distribution?
It seems that, typically, the domain is presented as being the set {0, 1, 2, ...}. But could I also think of the domain being the real line, with
$P(X = k) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k}}{k!}$ for $k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$
and
$P(X = k) = 0$ for $k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}^C$.


This question is motivated by considering the transformation of a Poisson random variable $X$, where it seems helpful to be able to contemplate $X$ taking on negative values (even if the probability of this occurring is $0$). But if the pmf of $X$ is only defined for nonnegative integers, then it wouldn't seem to make sense to consider $P(X = -1)$, because there is no definition for this expression.

How about using the Gamma function to generalize the domain?
